# How to stop Log Reader Agent from SQL/Command Line

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication

Say I've got replication on a SQL Server 2012 box set up.  Everything is working as expected, and the Log Reader Agent is running.

Now, say that I need to remove all traces of this publication/subscription from the database programmatically.  Previously, I had this working with SQL 2008R2.

The steps I was taking are -

1. Drop subscription at source database (sp_dropsubscription)
2. Drop subscription at target database (sp_droppullsubscription)
3. Drop publisher (sp_droppublication)
4. Remove everything else (sp_replicationdboption)
5. Remove databases

This used to work perfectly, but since upgrading to SQL 2012, when I try to drop the publisher, I get the following error -

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Only one Log Reader
>   Agent or log-related procedure (sp_repldone, sp_replcmds, and
>   sp_replshowcmds) can connect to a database at a time. If you executed
>   a log-related procedure, drop the connection over which the procedure
>   was executed or execute sp_replflush over that connection before
>   starting the Log Reader Agent or executing another log-related
>   procedure.

Now, I think I understand what's going on here, but I don't know how to prevent it.

What's the best way of stopping the Log Reader Agent, either via command line, or via SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Log Reader Agent is typically run via a SQL Agent job (unless you have some funky process that kicks it off from the command line). Given this you should be able to just query `msdb.sysjobs` for the job, and execute `msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job @job_name = (your agent job)`.

Comment: but, how the problem will be resolved after we stop the job?

Comment: This will help you find it:  select TOP 1 job_id , name
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs 
WHERE category_id IN (SELECT category_id 
                      FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories 
                      WHERE name = 'REPL-LogReader')

Answer (score 2):

```
select TOP 1 job_id 
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs 
WHERE category_id IN (SELECT category_id 
                      FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories 
                      WHERE name = 'REPL-LogReader')
```

Comment: Does that actually stop the agent?

Comment: This gets info about the job. Changing line 1 to `select TOP 1 *` instead of `select TOP 1 job_id` gives the job `name` to use in answer from @Nic.